# Cisco QSFP port to SAN(16G , 32G) Connection

Tags: cisco-nexus

Cisco has a Nexus 9000 model which supports FC. But all ports are QSFP, how can we connect FC to QSFP?

Model:
Cisco Nexus 9336C-FX2-E Switch

Port:
36 x 40/100-Gbps QSFP28 ports

Descriptions:
The Cisco Nexus 9336C-FX2-E Switch (Figure 2) is a 1RU switch that supports 7.2 Tbps of bandwidth and over 2.4 bpps. The switch can be configured to work as 1/10/25/40/50/100-Gbps or **as 16-, 32-Gbps Fibre Channel ports**[2] offering flexible options in a compact form factor. Breakout is supported on all ports. Please see feature table below for more information.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need breakouts for the QSFP28 ports - either QSFP28 to 4x SFP28 or QSFP+ to 4x SFP+ for DACs, or a QSFP28/+ short-wave transceiver on that end with a four-pair fiber fanout (MPO to 4x LC) and the appropriate single-lane FC transceivers on the other end.

Comment: Does breakout work for FC ? I cannot find any breakout specially for FC connectors. would you please guide me?

Comment: The exact parts should be in the documentation. Since the breakout is on the Nexus 9000 side, the FC side doesn't see anything from it.